# ggplot2: use label if object exists, otherwise choose default/NULL

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have a ggplot2 function that includes the following command:

```
sp <- sp + geom_point() + gs + scale_linetype_manual(values =
            c('solid',  'longdash','dashed', 'twodash', 'dotdash', 'dotted'), labels=labls)
```

This is used by users with different datasets. If I define the object labls as a vector (e.g. labls=c("cow","horse","chicken")) this works fine, of course. However, I want it to refer to the default labeling when the object does not exist (in this case: 1, 2, 3).

Is there a quick and elegant way to include this condition? I've stumbled upon the "ifelse" function, but am not sure how to use this in reference to the object I'm letting "labels" request?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `labels = waiver()` to specify that you want the defaults.

```
library(ggplot2)

create_plot <- function(df, labels) {
  if (missing(labels)) {
    labels <- waiver()
  }
  
  ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, linetype = Species)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c('longdash','dashed', 'twodash'), labels = labels)
}
```

Specifying `labels`

```
create_plot(iris, labels = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

[image: Non-default]

Not specifying `labels` and getting the defaults

```
create_plot(iris)
```

[image: Default]

Comment: Thank you, simple and elegant solution. Also a very useful command to know in general.